# Fatal IO error when using Python in screen session

Tags: python, debugging, gnu-screen

I'm running a python script in a screen session. That is: I open the screen session, start the script and intend to let it run in the background, shutting down the terminal.

When I re-open the screen session, it tells me a 'Fatal IO error: client killed' occurred. 
I don't think it's because of my specific code, since it runs fine as long as I stay active in the window (I don't detach the screen session).

What could be the cause of this and/or how could I troubleshoot?

Comment: Like any other problem, you need to strip it down to a minimal example to post here that replicates your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do that though. As I state in the question, it doesn't seem due to the python program so I'm wondering if it's the setup of screen, something someone else ran into, or such. What I'm looking for is, therefore, is expertise about the ins- and outs of screen.

Comment: `screen` itself isn't that complicated; it creates a pseudoterminal and provides that as the controlling terminal for your process.  Start looking at the parts of your code that do I/O.